# IOS App Crashing if we build and upload through azure pipeline (React native)

Tags: ios, azure-pipelines, app-store-connect

I have uploaded the build using xcode, it is working fine. But if i upload using azure pipeline, app is crashing(not able to open)

There is nothing wrong in code also

Comment: Could you please share enable the option 'Enable system diagnostics', and share the step logs? What the task you are using? Please share the yaml file.

Comment: @YujunDing-MSFT Thank you so much. Fixed it. I was using the wrong Provisional Profile

Comment: I am glad that you have resolved your question. Since you have resolved it, would you please convert your comment to the answer? This can be beneficial to other community members reading the answer, avoid spending a lot of time on a post that already has an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of provisional profile mismatch. After fixing that, it is working fine

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.